# If API is must for google places autocomplete in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using this link and its working but it shows warning

link:https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places

warning : util.js:210 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Please help .Thanks in advance.

```js
routerApp.directive('googleplace', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
            var options = {
                types: [],
                componentRestrictions: {}
            };
            scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);
            
            google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function(e) {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    model.$setViewValue(element.val());
                    //
                     scope.secondplacebox = scope.chosenPlace;
                    var latitude = scope.gPlace.getPlace().geometry.location.lat().toFixed(6);
             var longitude = scope.gPlace.getPlace().geometry.location.lng().toFixed(6);
             //alert(latitude );
       scope.Fn_SearchFood(latitude,longitude,scope.date);  
     });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Google API you need to set your API KEY. You need to create an API KEY and put that key to script.

[Google Developer API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/)

```
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=myKey"></script>
```

Comment: When I placed my API then I got error----js?libraries=places&sensor=false&key= AIzaSyDb_sP-jlvEvKsS6_7QTBwgXt0I4qCv1JY:34 Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized:

Answer (score 0):

for using GoogleApi you need to create a account for in foofle developer console and you need to mention the site url in which you will use the google api.

After account creation you will get a token key which will be placed in google api script.